# How to set focus to a Frame that overlays other controls, and still have the Frame visible on top of other controls

Tags: excel, vba

I have a standalone class file that creates and operates a date picker.  It uses only native VBA controls, uses no kernel calls and does not need any module files.  It accepts mouse or keyboard input to pick a day, month, and/or year.  It can be instantiated on a UserForm which acts like a popup dialog.  Or it can be instantiated on a Frame with acts like an overlay.  My issue is with the latter, where the Frame does not overlay other controls on the UserForm such as list box or multi page forms and is hidden where they share geography.

I have successfully been able to consistently get the Frame to overlay everything on the UserForm, but at that point the Frame does not have focus.  A mouse click is required to operate the date picker, because it does not recognize any keyboard input.  If I execute a setFocus either in the class when the date picker is generated, or with a call to the class after the date picker is generated, the date picker Frame is again behind other controls on the form.

Also, while in development, placing a break point in the class after the date picker is visible and before the setFocus is executed, the Frame does both overlay everything and respond to keyboard input, when execution is resumed.  So, something occurs in the development environment that allows that to happen.  I tried to implement a minor delay loop hoping it would replicate that something, but it did not.

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to move focus to the Frame after it has been made visible and have it remain on top of all controls?  From what I can see in Stackoverflow, this question has been asked and answered in the past without any real solution.

Example Code:
Create a UserForm and place a Label, a ListBox and a Frame anywhere on the form.  The placement and size do not matter for any of these items.
In the Code for the UserForm place this code.

```
    Dim aClass As CDatePicker
    Private Sub Label1_Click()
        aClass.setSelectedDate Label1
    End Sub

    Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
        Set aClass = New CDatePicker
        aClass.makeCalendar Nothing, Frame1
    End Sub
```

Create a Class module and paste this code there

```
    Option Explicit

    Private WithEvents aKey As MSForms.TextBox
    Private WithEvents lCancel As MSForms.Label
    Private aFrame As Object
    Private Sub lCancel_click()
                aFrame.Visible = False
    End Sub
    Private Sub aKey_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)

        Select Case KeyCode
                Case 99, 67:    lCancel_click
                Case 27:        lCancel_click
                Case Else: aFrame.Caption = Chr(KeyCode)
        End Select
        KeyCode = 0
    End Sub

    Sub makeCalendar(oTheDate As Object, aForm As Object)
        Set aFrame = aForm
        With aFrame
                .Visible = False
                .Width = aForm.Parent.Width - 18
                .Height = aForm.Parent.Height - 38
                .Top = 3
                .Left = 3
                .ZOrder (0)  ' this is what makes the frame overlay all controls
                .Caption = ""
        End With
        
        Set aKey = aFrame.Controls.Add("forms.textbox.1", "aKey", True)
        With aKey
                .Height = 2
                .Width = 2
        End With
        
        Set lCancel = aFrame.Controls.Add("forms.label.1", "lCancel", True)
        With lCancel
                .Top = 50
                .Left = 5
                .BorderStyle = fmBorderStyleSingle
                .SpecialEffect = fmSpecialEffectRaised
                .Caption = "Cancel"
                .TextAlign = fmTextAlignCenter
        End With
    End Sub
    Sub setSelectedDate(lCkDate As Object)
        With aFrame
                .Visible = True
        End With
        aKey.SetFocus
    End Sub
```

When you click on the Label the Frame is shown, but the ListBox overlays the frame and is still visible.  Type any key and the Frame Caption will show that key.

If you comment the last line (aKey.setFocus) in the class, and then click on the Label the Frame is shown, and the ListBox is not visible.  Type any key and nothing happens.  If you click anywhere on the Frame and then type any key the Frame Caption will show that key.

If you place a break on the last line (aKey.setFocus) in the class, and then click on the Label, the Frame is shown.  The ListBox is not visible.  Resuming the execution, type on any key and the Frame caption will show that key.

Is there any way to replicate that behavior outside of the development environment?

Comment: Nobody can help you only reading a story, without pasting the code in discussion, or sending a link to the code source. [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [Minimal reproductible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)...

Comment: Code example added to post

Answer (score 0):

This look to me as a timing issue, then I normally use application.ontime:

add a module with:

```
Sub DoStuff(tb As String)
Dim ctl As Control
For Each ctl In UserForm1.Controls 'for easiness opening default instance of Userform1)
    If ctl.Name = tb Then ctl.SetFocus
Next
End Sub
```

and adjust your "setSelectedDate"code as follows:

```
Sub setSelectedDate(lCkDate As Object)
    With aFrame
            .Visible = True
    End With
 ' aKey.SetFocus
       Application.OnTime Now(), "'DoStuff " & aKey.Name & "'"
 End Sub
```

Comment: as the setSelectedDate is in a class module, not sure how to construct the DoStuff specification in the OnTime call so that it can be found.  Tried Module1.DoStuff and it is not found.

Comment: thanks to EvR for inspiration on a solution.  If I add a **DoEvents** after the Frame is made visible and before I setFocus on it, it works.

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered the solution:  Add a **DoEvents** statement after making the Frame visible and before setting focus on the Frame.  The Frame remains "on top" and it also handles keyboard input.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to change the class `setSelectedDate` method in this way:

```
   Sub setSelectedDate(lCkDate As Object)
        With lCkDate
            .Visible = True
            .ZOrder (0)
            .SetFocus
        End With
    End Sub
```

And the calling event to be transformed in:

```
    Private Sub Label1_Click()
        aClass.setSelectedDate Frame1
    End Sub
```